# Mostar archivo pdf Alojado en una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysql-workbench, php7

Este es el código con el  que inserto el archivo.(lo inserta correctamente) pero cuando  lo muestro, muestra el  nombre en el div pero para mostrar el archivo me manda el  error (Error
Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF.),   si muestro los archivos que subo directo con el  worckbench si muestra los archivos.

```
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
$fecha_archivo = $_POST['fecha_archivo'];
// archivo temporal (ruta y nombre).
$binario_nombre_temporal=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
// leer del archvio temporal .. el binario subido.
$binario_contenido = addslashes(fread(fopen($binario_nombre_temporal, "rb"), filesize($binario_nombre_temporal)));
// Obtener del array FILES (superglobal) los datos del binario .. nombre, tabamo y tipo.
$binario_nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$binario_peso=$_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$binario_tipo=$_FILES['archivo']['type'];
//Se insertan los datos.
$insertar = "INSERT INTO indicadores (id_departamento, correo_usuario, nombre, archivo, peso, tipo, fecha_carga, estatus, fecha_creacion) VALUES ('$id_departamento', '$correo', '$binario_nombre', '$archivo', '$binario_peso', '$binario_tipo', NOW(), 1, '$fecha_archivo')" or die(mysql_error());
$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $insertar) or die(mysql_error());
```

este es el  codigo con el que lo muestro.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from documentos where id = '$id_pdf'") or die (mysql_error());
    $resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Lectura de PDF</h4>
                    <strong><p>'.$resultado[nombre].'</p></strong>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="user_data">
                    <object data="data:application/pdf;base64, '.base64_encode($resultado[archivo]).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:800px;width:100%; position:relative;" ></object>

                    <div style="position:relative; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00); width:98%; height:250px; top:-850px;"></div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

**De esta manera agrego la imagen en wockbeanch.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar como subes los archivos con el  worckbench? Quizá ayude a identificar que esta haciendo mal el código php, quizá sea el `addslashes` que usas, además, en el código que muestras para almacenar el pdf usas la tabla **indicadores** y en la lectura usas la tabla **documentos**.

Comment: Si, una disculpa al mostrar coloque la  incorrecta, pero si  es la de indicadores la  que utilizo, te comparto como la subo al editar mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La solución fue esta**

```
$pdf=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, file_get_contents($binario_nombre_temporal));
//Se insertan los datos.
$insertar = "INSERT INTO indicadores (id_departamento, correo_usuario, nombre, archivo, peso, tipo, fecha_carga, estatus, fecha_creacion) VALUES ('$id_departamento', '$correo', '$binario_nombre', '$pdf', '$binario_peso', '$binario_tipo', NOW(), 1, '$fecha_archivo')" or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Si, yo acabo de terminar una prueba y la culpa era del `addslashes` así que creo te sobra también `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Seguramente en tu caso no está haciendo nada, pero en otras configuraciones podría corromper el fichero como en tu intento anterior.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación.